# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error in my Restify server

Tags: heroku, cors, restify, preflight

I am using Restify in my Heroku server. I am getting this error:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xxx.xxx.com/charging. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://xxx.xxx.com' is therefore not allowed access.
The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

My Restify configuration is:

```
server
.use(restify.fullResponse())
.use(restify.bodyParser())
.use(restify.queryParser())
.use(restify.CORS({
    origins: ['https://xxx.xxx.com', 'http://xxx.xxx.com']
}));
```

What is missing in my configuration?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Comment: That didn't solve my issue. Is there a way to redirect all http requests to https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases, you may need to use `server.pre` instead of `server.use`.

https://github.com/restify/node-restify/issues/573